# Using Javascript in Google Web Optimizer Page Sections

Tags: javascript, google-website-optimizer

Is it possible to use Javascript in the content of a page section variation? I want different variations to make different Javascript function calls, so I have variation content like:

Variation 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">my_func('abc');</script>
```

Variation 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">my_func('def');</script>
```

However, when I preview my page, I can't verify that my_func(content){ alert(content); } is actually being run. Does GWO not support JS content, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Javascript in the content of a page section variation?

Yes it is.

> Does GWO not support JS content, or am I missing something?

You are doing something wrong. GWO does support JS content.